# Какой корень в слове выразить?

Tags: глаголы, морфемный-разбор

Какой корень в слове "выразить"?

Answer (score 2):

Корень -*раз*-, приставка *вы*-...

Без приставки сей корень присутствует в слове **раж** :

> Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980) А уж Фил **вошел в раж** и стал бить быка, как грушу.

С двумя приставками : *пре/об/раж/ение*.

Comment: >**ПОДРАЖАТЬ**
кому, чему, следовать примеру, образцу, делать что в подражанье кому, брать с кого пример, стараться уподобиться.
| Не подражай ему, вост., сиб. не балуй, не давай потачки, повадки. Во многих стихотвореньях Лермонтова заметны подражания Пушкину, Жуковскому и другим. Легче подражается, чем создается. Подражатель, -ница, кто подражает. Подражательный, к подражанью относящийся. Подражать, у Рейфа, от другой; у Шимкевича от дорога; по мне, от ражать, разить: **выражать, изображать, подражать.**

>Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.

Answer (score 2):

По Зализняку -раз-http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C ,а вот в "Школьном словаре строения слов" Потихи, по Текучёву,по Тихонову - выраз-. Школьная грамматика говорит о том, что -раз- это исторический корень, а в современном языке выразить, поразить, преобразить - разные по значению слова, и корни у них разные:по/раз/и/ть,выраз/и/ть,пре/образ/и/ть, зараз/и/ть

http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C(%D1%81%D1%8F)/

Comment: Можно и с другой стороны зайти!

Есть ли связь у корня *раз/раж* с корнем *ряд/ряж*? Модно наряжен - выражен во всей своей красе, старинный обряд - образ действий, заряженный порохом - зараженный вирусом, ядерный заряд - смертельная зараза, боевой отряд - отражение врага, навел порядок - поразил чистотой (футбольная поговорка : *порядок бьет* {поражает} *класс*). Ну, и на десерт - перекличка классиков : 

"Балуй, анафема, *разрази тебя громом!*" (Бунин) - "И в то же мгновение резкий удар страшной силы, *как разряд молнии, разразился*, казалось, не только над Улей, а в ней самой" (Фадеев)

Comment: Это Вы о чём? Далеко же Вас завели лингвистические изыскания.Раз/раж с корнем ряд/ряж - ничего общего не имеют.Наряд-ряд, снаряд,орудие,даже ресницы, ряса-исторически родственны, а корень -раз- раз(один, однажды) резать, надрез, разить, поразить, резвый. А вот выражать, подражать - от исчезнувшего сущ. ражь-черта, характер. Есть ещё версия, что подражать - от ст.-слав. глагола дражать, дражить - от "дорога", т.е. подражать- идти по той же дороге. Так что это совсем разные корни.

Comment: Мне кажется, что к слову "подражать" однокоренным будет "дразнить", ведь, подражая кому-нибудь, мы фактически дразним его

Comment: >Так что это совсем разные корни.

Пример официальной этимологии. Фасмер начинает, Трубачев его "мягко поправляет"))) :

 **РАЖИЙ**
ражой "коренастый, сильный, крепкий, дородный", вологодск., олонецк., яросл., тверск., пенз., тамб., вост.-русск. Как и дородный, происходит от род... Сюда же раже, ражо "много, обильно", ражево – то же, вологодск., тверск., владим., ражовой "красивый, бодрый, крепкий", арханг...

[Слово ражий не имеет ничего общего с род, рожать и объясняется как прилаг. с суф. -jь от слав. rаzъ, русск. раз; см. Трубачев...]

А слово **раж** - вообще французское, надо же)))

Comment: Согласна,ражий- исконно русск. слово. Общепринятой этимологии не имеет. Одни ученые объясняют его как слово того же корня, что и дородный; -dj > ж (с перегласовкой о/а). Другие толкуют как суф. производное (суф. -j; зj > ж) от раз. Войти в раж - раж - франц. заимствование. А вот с Виктором не согласна. Подражать и дразнит- не однокоренные. Вот раздражать и дразнит - да. А подражать- не дразнить, а делать так же,идти по одной дороге. Это иногда раздражает, а иногда радует.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "раж"в переводе с французского обозначает ярость. В выражении "вошел в раж", приведенном для примера о ярости и говорится. Не вижу ничего общего со словом  "выразить", которое пытался объяснит Дерзкий.

Comment: Именно так. Ну а что там Дерзкий пишет - это его тараканы.

Comment: Светлана, несколько ранее Вас я уже написал :
>А слово раж - вообще французское, надо же)))
(15 Сен 20:26) Дерзкий

К заданному вопросу (*какой корень в слове выразить*) все это сбоку припека, чисто побочные рассуждения и тд. Да, я просмотрел все словари и добавил к слову **раж** мое смешливое удивленнное *надо же*...

К Вашему "ответу" здешний сатанист провякал свой болотный коммент, привыкайте, если сможете))) И исправьте опечатку в своем сообщении, пжлст, а то как-то стремно у Вас.